# Map with collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, google-maps, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using map inside collapsing toolbar. It works great in Lollipop but when i try to run same app in older version, the black screen remains after scrolling. I have tested with Samsung Galaxy SII with android version 4.0.4

Here is my code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.elsner.mhealth.MapsActivity"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main_activity_toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="@color/white"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/map_address"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I can confirm this happens on API 10. Have not found a solution yet.